# run script file after visiting certain url (with string)

Tags: jquery, regex, string, path

I have successfully made a script that runs a script file after visiting a certain URL, but if I add whatever string after the `/`, it doesn't work - like `url.com/blog/?utm_source?000`

```
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('blog/') >= 0) {
    $.getScript("/user/documents/upload/BLOG.js");
}
```

Any ideas?